# Where is located syscall_table in kernel x86_64?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm trying to add new System Call to Linux Kernel(x86_64). Based on [this article](http://techeclipse.com/how-to/linux-kernel/) which explained how to add System Call to Kernel(x86). The article says I need to define my System Call name in a file called `syscall_table_32.S` which is located in `src/arch/x86/syscall_table_32.S`.

But in my case, there is no file named `syscall_table_32.S` or `syscall_table_64.S` in the kernel source! There isn't even a directory for x64 System Call table in `src/arch/`.

So, where is `syscall_table_64.S` defined in kernel 3.13.0-14-generic (x86_64) ?
Where can I define a new system call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the system call table in linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652555/where-is-the-system-call-table-in-linux-kernel)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Version 3.3 onward are different from 2.X that the guide use. You should look for the `syscalls` directory, in the `arch/x86/` directory. So is:

```
cd /kernel-src/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl
```

`kernel-src` being the directory where your kernel sources resides. A good idea would be reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10052600/792066) in SO and compare it with your resource.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using kernel version `4.9.329` and `syscall_32.tbl` directory was `./arch/×86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl`. It also tested on kernel version `6.2.1`.