# Debian 10 System Call Table is empty

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, system-calls

I was trying to follow a course guide about kernel and it was going good until the instructions said that i need to open **syscall_64.tbl** and write a line in there. in the video the file is full but when i open mine i see nothing. and since i am beginner with kernel i actually have no idea what i am doing. The instruction is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exSm7.png). I hope i can explain myself clear. How can i solve this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the following article: [Where is located syscall_table in kernel x86_64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26681507/6630084)